# LinkedList delete functionality is deleting 2 nodes

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I'm creating my own linkedList implementation and am somehow deleting 2 nodes at once. I do not understand why. I have tried deleting different integers and it seems to really like to delete the second entry in the list.

When I don't use the delete method the list traverses correctly. This leads me to believe that I am deleting incorrectly. I am keeping track of the previous node with the `place_node` various.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def prepend(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node


    def traversal(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp is not None:
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next


    def append(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        place_node = None
        temp = self.head
        while temp is not None:
            place_node = temp
            temp = temp.next
        new_node.next = place_node.next
        place_node.next = new_node

    def delete(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        temp = self.head

        while temp is not None:

            if temp.data == data:
                break
            place_node = temp
            temp = temp.next
            place_node.next = temp.next


class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


ehren = LinkedList()

ehren.prepend(5)
ehren.prepend(3)
ehren.prepend(8)
ehren.append(6)
print(" delete the number")
ehren.delete(6)
print("linked list***********")
ehren.traversal()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete` method should be implemented like this:

```
  def delete(self, data):
      prev = None
      temp = self.head

      while temp is not None:
          if temp.data == data:
              if prev is None: # Handle the case when we are deleting the head which has no previous node
                  self.head = self.head.next
              else:
                  prev.next = temp.next
              break
          prev = temp
          temp = temp.next
```

Since this is a singly-linked-list, you need to keep track of the node before the target, and to delete means to set the `next` pointer of the previous node to the `next` pointer of the node to be deleted, thus making the selected node disappear.

Comment: @Ehren You should accept the answer if it correctly answers your question.